# How to display User Permission in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

So I am currently setting some user permissions upon creation to Django user's.

I would like to display a table of all the users as well as information about them such as username, password permissions etc..

The code to do this look's similar to this.

```
<table id='usersTable'>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Last Login</th>
                        <th>Expiry Date</th>
                        <th>Permission</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for user in userlist %}
                    <tr id='{{ user.id }}' class='user-row urow'>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check" class='userSelection'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="status"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.last_login}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.userprofile.date_expiry}}</td>
                        {% load user_perm %}
                        <td>
                            {% if user|check_permission:'2018_map_view' %}
                               I have 2018 access
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if user|check_permission:'2017_map_view' %}
                               I have 2017 access
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

I have on the bottom the attempted code to display each user permission in the table however it does not seem to be working.

I have my templatetags code that looks like this

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter()
def check_permission(user, permission):
        permission = user.has_perm(permission)
        print(permission)
        return user.has_perm(permission)
```

I believe the problem lies within my user in userList and it is having problem looping through all user's but I am unsure how to fix this. Any insite would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this better:

from django import template
register = template.Library()

```
@register.filter()
def check_permission(user, permission):
    if user.user_permissions.filter(codename = permission).exists():
        return True
    return False
```

It checks in a efficient way if the permission exists, then, inside template load tags and use it:

```
{%load mytags%}  <!-- Assuming this is your tags.py file name -->

{% if user|check_permission:'2018_map_view' %}
        ... do your staff ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @jsanchez, I thought I had tried this but I couldn't get it working either guess I had something mixed up!.

Comment: My pleasure @swilson0897